# Como criar um atributo Foreign key e unique ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: sql, oracle

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira, ou qual a melhor maneira, de restringir uma relação entre duas entidades, sendo que uma não pode se repetir nessa relação. Tenho as tabelas 'Clientes' e 'Telefone'. Porém 1 cliente pode ter vários telefones, então fiz uma relação 'Clientes_Telefones'. O problema é que não pode se repetir o número do telefone, mas ele tem que existir na

```
tabela telefones.`create table cliente(
    cod_cli int primary key,
    nome varchar(40)
);

create table telefone(
    identificador int primary key,
    numero int unique
);

 create table cliente_telefone(
    id_cli_tel int primary key,
    cod_cli int,
    identificador int,
    constraint fk_cli foreign key(cod_cli) references cliente(cod_cli),
    constraint fk_tel foreign key(identificador) references telefone(identificador)
);
```

Comment: Se o cliente só pode ter um telefone, não existe a necessidade da tabela auxiliar [cliente_telefone], basta você adicionar a coluna e foreign key na tabela cliente.

Comment: Olá @Wéllingthon M. de Souza. No meu caso citei que o cliente pode ter vários telefones, porém nessa tabela de relação, o id do telefone pode repetir somente uma vez. É como se o atributo 'identificador' (id_telefone) fosse foreign key e unique ao mesmo tempo na tabela cliente_telefone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma Unique Key Constraint resolve

```
ALTER TABLE cliente_telefone
ADD CONSTRAINT cliente_telefone_uk UNIQUE (numero);
```

Documentação : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm

Comment: Está errada esta resposta.

Comment: O campo seria "identificador" , seria mais simples o telefone ser a própria chave.